# Crash of Windows Settings and Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

Tags: windows-10, crash

I just purchased an Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming Laptop.
It comes with Windows 10 Home pre-installed. It has a GPU from NVIDIA (GeForce® GTX 1650).

I made the initial configuration and installed few software:

- Office365, Adobe Creative Cloud, Adobe Premiere: licenced
- Notepad++ from MS store
- BitDefender AV
- Firefox, Thunderbird
- KeePass

At some point (2 days after setup), a strange behaviour appeared.
When launching the Windows settings, the window opens, shows no content then diapears after 3 seconds.

The Windows application event log contains, at each occurence:

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0x9d9d9332
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.17763.168, time stamp: 0x4b439076
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000708ab2
Faulting process id: 0x2d8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d493169446e2bf
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 426010f9-5e67-47ee-a88d-36a3781100c4
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.2.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

1. Tried to update Windows. Same behaviour.
2. Tried to de-install all software one by one, using the "old" Control Panel. Same behaviour.
3. De-installed BitDefender and reactived Windows AV. Same behaviour.

Could this be due somehow to some conflict with the GPU?
Has anyone seen this issue?

Comment: Have you ran any software that claimed to disable Windows 10 spying features?  Any program that disable or uninstalled UWP applications could be at fault.  Typically, this level of system corrupt, requires you to simply reinstall Windows 10.  There are ways to figure out the reason you are unable to open UWP application, but it requires extensive knowledge, of what commands you ran to break your system

Comment: **Could this be due somehow to some conflict with the GPU?"** - This is absolutely not caused by your GPU.  **Has anyone seen this issue?** - Yes

Answer (score 0):

I add the same issue.

- Re-installing Windows (erasing all data) from recovery USB did not change the situation: opening control panel still closing after 2-3 seconds.
- Performing a Lenovo Recovery using the NOVO button did neither change anything.

I shipped back the notebook to Lenovo and they apparently re-installed Windows. Issue has gone.

Comment: If "***Re-installing Windows (erasing all data) from recovery USB***" did not fix the problem, they probably did more than re-install windows.  If your recovery installation were corrupt, the CRC check would have failed.  Something else was wrong.